# deleteRow sometimes deletes the right row and sometimes not in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table. At the end of each row tehere is a href "X" which deletes this row. This is pretty simple. Now when you click "X" for any row 2 it deletes row 2, but then when you click on row 3 it deleted row 4.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<table id="my_table" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Custom0</td>
    <td><a title="my title text" id="1" href="#" class="someclass" onclick="deleteRows(0)">X</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Custom1</td>
    <td> <a title="my title text" id="2" href="#" class="someclass" onclick="deleteRows(1)">X</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Custom2</td>
    <td> <a title="my title text" id="3" href="#" class="someclass" onclick="deleteRows(2)">X</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Custom3</td>
    <td> <a title="my title text" id="4" href="#" class="someclass" onclick="deleteRows(3)">X</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Custom4</td>
    <td> <a title="my title text" id="5" href="#" class="someclass" onclick="deleteRows(4)">X</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Custom5</td>
    <td> <a title="my title text" id="6" href="#" class="someclass" onclick="deleteRows(5)">X</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and Javascript

```
function deleteRows(row) {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('my_table'); // table reference
  tbl.deleteRow(row);
}
```

You can play wit it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nTJtv/13/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have hard-coded the row numbers, so after the first deletion they are out of sync.  The `<table>` element's `.rows` property is "live", so removing one means the numbers no longer line up with your HTML.

Instead, consider passing `this.parentNode.parentNode` to the function and using it to determine which row to delete:

```
<a title="my title text" id="6" href="#" class="someclass" onclick="deleteRows(this.parentNode.parentNode)">X</a>
```

Then use `removeChild()` in the function:

```
function deleteRows(row) {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('my_table'); // table reference
  tbl.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].removeChild(row);
}
```

Edit: The `<tr>` is a child of the `<tbody>` element, so that must be the parent from which it is removed.

http://jsfiddle.net/nTJtv/19/

If you would really rather do it with `deleteRow()`, then loop through the rows to find the one passed to the function and delete it:

```
function deleteRows(row) {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('my_table'); // table reference
  // Loop over the table .rows collection to find the one passed into the function
  for (var i=0; i<tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    if (row == tbl.rows[i]) {
      // And delete it
      tbl.deleteRow(i); 
      return;
    }
  } 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nTJtv/21/

Comment: Its not working. The rows aren't deleting at all. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/nTJtv/23/

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this? Using jQuery isn't hard to add into existing files/sites.

HTML:

```
<table id="my_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Custom0</td>
    <td><span title="my title text" id="1" class="someclass">X</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Custom1</td>
    <td><span title="my title text" id="2" class="someclass">X</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.someclass').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```